# How to enable full screen youtube video on Android with HTML5 app?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I'm working on a html5 app and i have a section with a videos of youtube..on iOS works well,so opens on full screen but on android doesn't.

My code is:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VwHa2ARYIdA?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='200%' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/VwHa2ARYIdA?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0' allowfullscreen  ></iframe>
```

it works for me...

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Android 8 but `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"` seems works.  I also have `webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" `